# Python 3.3 - Getting Header and redirect the results

Tags: windows, python-3.x, http-headers, output, fileoutputstream

I would like to create a script that look to a file, read each line (which are url) and fetch the HTTP header for me. 
I have a questions : 
I try to redirect the result to a text file but, anyhow I try, it is not working.

Can someone help me with my code please ?

```
import urllib.request
import sys
open('sorti.txt','w')
sorti = open("sorti.txt",'w')
print('Creation de sorti.txt')

text_file = open ("id.txt", "r")
text_file.read().strip('\n') 
for lines in text_file:
    urllib.request.urlopen('lines').write.sorti()
    header = urllib.request.parse_http_list(lines).write.sorti()
    sys.stdout(sorti)
text_file.close
sorti.close
```

Comment: have you tried it? did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are looking for something like this

```
    URL1
    header_1: value
    ...
    header_n: value

    URL2
    header_1: value
    ...
    header_n: value
```

change the code as follows:

```
text_file = open ("id.txt", "r")
for line in text_file:
    sorti.write(line) // writes the current url
    obj = urllib.request.urlopen(line)
    headers = dict(obj.info()) // gets the headers
    for (h,v) in headers.items(): // write all with the specified format
        sorti.write("{0}: {1}\n".format(h, v))
    sorti.write("\n")
sorti.close
```

Those `write.sorti()` will not work.